# Convert 8-bit binary file to ASCII

Tags: shell, binary, ascii, 8-bit

I have a file composed of one line full of 8-bit binary number, i.e. like this:

```
01010100 01101000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01101010 01110101 01110011 01110100 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01100010 01100101 01100111 01101001 01101110
```

I know for a fact that they are supposed to correspond to a ASCII symbol. For example `01010100`correspond to the letter `T` ("capital t").

I'd like to convert it all to a txt file (there are in the list some `\n` and I've got a feeling that somehow ASCII-art will appear doing such. Can ou point me some shell method? I'd like to achieve that through the shell. Or at the very least Python.

Comment: All the numbers you show evaluate to a number in the range 0..127 (0x00..0x7F) and therefore fall within the range of ASCII characters.  What's the problem?  Is the content of the file actually a series of 1 and 0 characters with a space after every group of 8 digits that must be transformed?  (I'll observe it is a very wasteful way of storing or transferring data, using 72 bits for each 8-bit (7-bit?) value.)

Comment: A very simple C program can do the job pretty easily, reading from standard input and writing to standard output.  For example: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char number[9];
    while (scanf("%8s", number) == 1)
        putchar(strtol(number, 0, 2));
    return 0;
}`.  When run on the data you show, it yields: `This is just the begin`.  Clearly, there's barely any error checking and only minimal error prevention; you get what you get if the data is mal-formatted after all.  But the job is not very complex.  (The C code needs to be on at least 3 lines.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could get a hold of a acsii binary conversion table and read it into an associative array.  e.g. ascii["110000"]=0  etc.  and then just plow through the file